# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Yes the path exist, yes I'm using absolute path

Tags: python, compiler-errors

I'm tying to split my json file into multiple pieces.I keep running into this error even though the files and paths exist

[image of file path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJqIW.png)

```
import os
import json

with open(os.path.join(r'C:\Users\flipp\Downloads\decompressed', 'signalmedia-1m.json'), 'r',
          encoding='utf-8') as f1:
    ll = [json.loads(line.strip()) for line in f1.readlines()]

    
    print(len(ll))

   
    size_of_the_split=2000
    total = len(ll) // size_of_the_split

  
    print(total+1)

    for i in range(total+1):
        json.dump(ll[i * size_of_the_split:(i + 1) * size_of_the_split], open(
            r"C:\Users\flipp\Downloads\smaller files\usedData"+ str(i+1) + ".json", 'w',
            encoding='utf8'), ensure_ascii=False, indent=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the image you posted it looks like the file is not a json file but is a zip file.

To check this, I think you can select the option to show file extensions as described [here.](https://www.howtogeek.com/205086/beginner-how-to-make-windows-show-file-extensions/)